# Flutter CupertinoSwitch background color change

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

How can i change the color , walkways show me to white - when I am trying active color than change the whole border color. Anyone I want to change only like the image switch color - Orange and the background color white.

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0):

While default color is white because of

> Defaults to [CupertinoColors.white] when null.

We can use `thumbColor` to assign color based on active status.

```dart
CupertinoSwitch(
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                thumbColor: on ? Colors.white : Colors.amber,
                trackColor: Colors.white,
                value: on,
                onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                  on = !on;
                }),
              )
```

**Demo Widget**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class MyAppH extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAppH({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyAppH> createState() => _MyAppHState();
}

class _MyAppHState extends State<MyAppH> {
  bool on = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CupertinoSwitch(
          activeColor: Colors.white,
          thumbColor: on ? Colors.white : Colors.amber,
          trackColor: Colors.white,
          value: on,
          onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
            on = !on;
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: there show some error in ThumbColor?

Comment: in my case it is fine, can you share the errors?

Comment: the cupertinoSwitch didnot find , thumbColor? is there need maybe required? how can i do it.

Comment: check your import having `import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';`

Comment: Does it solve the issue?

Comment: https://ibb.co/4ft036T see the error, brother

Comment: try demo widget.  Let me know if you get it

Comment: can you explain me, how can i required this in CupertinoSwitch.

Comment: Depends on where you like to require it, and it would be better to make ask on another question.

Comment: i didnot solve the problem

Comment: Run this widget separately and check if it works, if does, consider marking as an answer and create a separate question to have focusing on  that part.

Comment: https://ibb.co/TTS6rhd
https://ibb.co/4jq9swk

Comment: there some problem in switch background , how can I do it white?

Comment: use `activeColor` and `trackColor`

Comment: Can you help me to make a simple coding to done it?

Comment: Consider creating a new question by following  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)